# Effective string search in the large list of text paragraphs

Tags: python, list, concurrency

There is a large 200MB text file (built of paragraphs, separated by blank lines) containing users' information (Id and Job Title) that I have to read and then search for the provided userIds (123456, 111111, 123457, ...).

The text file example:

```
   123456 some text
   Java Programmer
   some text
   ...
   111111 some text
   some text
   C++ Programmer
   some text
   ...
   123456 some text
   C++ Programmer
   ...
   123457 some text
   Python Programmer
   ...
```

I've read this text file into a list, splitting the paragraphs by '\n\n' delimiter:

```
file = open(largeFilePath)
lines_list = file.read().split('\n\n')
```

Now, I have to search this list for the provided Ids (either numeric or alphanumeric).
The sequential search of a single userId in a list of about 200M characters takes about 20-30 seconds, and there are50-100 users (at least) to search for.

I'm looking for a way to parallel these searches.

What would be the suggested method to solve this problem?

Thanks

Zeev

Comment: since `lines_list` is a list of lists you can put it into a `pandas` data frame which will make searching for specific users efficient and fast

Comment: Put it in a database and index the data

Comment: to  gold_cy, I've read a bit about and would be really grateful for an example. Thanks

Comment: to  Torxed , It will take a lot of time to insert such a 200MB file into DB. These files (like the mentioned one) are some software systems output and there might be tens of. So the DB is not a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should index them into a dictionary:

```
def _extract_id(user_data):
    return user_data[0].partition()[0]

d = {_extract_id(data): data for data in lines_list}

>>> d["myid"]
"..."
```

Results will return much faster.